Can anyone run Grass from within QGIS version 3.36.2?
I get the same error message no matter what Grass module I try to run from Processing.
Current mapset warning has always been there, I am talking of the next warnings which actually leads to failure:

WARNING: Unable to create index
WARNING: Unable to copy table  for layer 1 from vector_6645f234b321815@PERMANENT to 
WARNING: Failed to copy attribute table to output vector map
I have tried creating new .shp files from scratch with next to no content but still same errors

I also encountered this error and helped by the discussion in this QGIS ticket, avoided it by disabling QGIS' use of the v.external GRASS tool when preparing data:
Go to Settings > Options and in the Processing tab, expand the Providers section and under the GRASS section, uncheck the 'use v.external...' option:

